# parsing international numerals

Tags: javascript, internationalization

I'm trying to figure out how my script will behave if rendered in a browser using Chinese (or other) locale using Chinese numerals (or another non-Latin symbol set). Can't seem to find any info on this on the interwebs.

Looking at the page
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString
we see examples of localized numbers when converting from number to string, but what about the other way around? I tried `parseInt("一二三")` in IE11 debug console which returned `NaN`, but I'm not using Chinese Windows. Could someone test this?

My confusion comes from JavaScript having loosely typed data, so what if I end up running into an implicit string-to-number conversion, such as this:

```
var a = "١٢٣";
var b = .01;
console.log(a*b);
```

Mind you my variables a and b could come from user input in a more complex example. How can you make sure that input coming from a non-Latin symbology is converted to the right number-representation internally before you do arithmetic if parseInt and implicit conversion don't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't work for several reasons. Notice firstly that while there is a `toLocalString` but there is no `parseLocalStringInt` or `fromLocaleString`. Secondly javascript only really does implicit type coercion when particular operators are used e.g. `==`. `*` however can't be used in this fashion and even `==` and other operators only support very limited coercion in comparison with what you are describing.

This coercion can still be very dangerous or useful depending on your point of view e.g.
`0 == false` is true
but `0 === false` is false but it certainly isn't as powerful and you think it is.

Comment: I agree - the JS language spec should provide functions `parseLocalStringInt` or `fromLocaleString` (or extend `parseInt`) to handle these i18n scenarios. In the meanwhile you'll have manually parse a non-Latin number string and look for the right character codes?